# Select statement for over 500k records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I'm using this `SELECT` Statment

```
SELECT ID, Code, ParentID,... 
FROM myTable WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ParentID = 0x0
```

This Statment is repeated each 15min (Through Windows Service)
The problem is the database become slow to other users when this query is runnig.
What is the best way to avoid slow performance while query is running?

Comment: You should investigate what is the reason why the database becomes slow, can the query be improved and maybe also think do you really need to fetch 500k rows every time, what are you doing with them?

Comment: If you main intent is to avoid impacting other users, add the `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` hint to the end of the query. If you want to speed up this query, add an index on `ParentID` along with the columns in the select list or change the clustered index to `ParentID`.

Comment: @JamesZ normally the result of that query is about 25 up to 50 records, but I have to use that query to find them. Then I have some calculation with other database depanding on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an execution plan for your query and inspect it.

- Is the `ParentId` field indexed?
- Are there other ways you might optimize the query?

Is it possible to increase the performance of the server that is hosting SQL Server?

- Does it need more disk or RAM?
- Do you have separate drives (spindles) for operating system, data, transaction logs, temporary databases?

Something else to consider - must you always retrieve the very latest values from this table for your application, or might it be possible to cache prior results and use those for some length of time?

Comment: Is the ParentId field indexed? Yes,   Are there other ways you might optimize the query? I don't know this is the only way I know.  No need for more RAM

Comment: Have you generated and looked at an execution plan for the query?

Answer (score -1):

Seems your table got huge number of records. You can think of implementing page-wise retrieval of data. You can first request for say TOP 100 rows and then having multiple calls to fetch rest of data.

I still don't understand need to run such query every 15 mins. You may think of implementing a stored procedure which can perform majority of processing and return you a small subset of data. This will be good improvement if it suits your requirement.